# Girl turns into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, vampire, dragons, shape-shifter

I'm looking for a book about a girl that turns into a dragon.  She is picked up and sent to a magic academy because they think she has magic abilities. She was raised by werewolves and eventually falls for a lion shapeshifter. Vampires want to drink the dragon blood. One who drank it turns back human.

Comment: The first two sentences exactly fit one of Ursula le Guin's Earthsea stories, but the rest means it can't be that.

Answer (score 5):

The first two sentences are very close the short story "Dragonfly" appearing in the anthology [*Tales From Earthsea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_Earthsea) by [Ursula K Le Guin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin). In which a young woman, *part* of whose true name is "Irian," is pulled along in the guise of a boy to the school of magic on Roke island by an erstwhile lover and a somewhat failed sorcerer from Roke as a prank on his former teachers. She is discovered to be a dragon born into human form, a form which she abandons at the end of the story. The girl/dragon makes an appearance in the final (?) book of Earthsea, [*The Other Wind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Other_Wind).

As rand al'thor noted, the conflicts with the remainder of your question, however.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the "[Blood Destiny](https://www.goodreads.com/series/99352-blood-destiny)" series by Helen Harper. Its about a girl called Mack who lives with a pack of shapeshifters. When the Alpha is killed, it brings Corrigan, the lord Alpha, to the pack. Mack finds out she is a dragon and ends up training at the mage's academy.